# AngularJS Best Practices for modifying view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I currently have an Angular application with one module.  This module defines a controller and a service.  I'm currently using the service to update my view.  Should services update view logic? Or should this be done in a separate Angular component?

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as AppCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
  <button ng-click="AppCtrl.getPeople()" ng-model="AppCtrl.getPeopleButtonText" ng-bind="AppCtrl.getPeopleButtonText"></button>
  <button ng-click="AppCtrl.clearPeople()">Clear</button>
  {{AppCtrl.errorMessage}}
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.grid'])
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', "PersonService", function ($scope, PersonService) {

    var controllerScope = this;
    controllerScope.getPeopleButtonText = "Get People";

    this.getPeople = function(){
      PersonService.getPeople($scope, controllerScope);
    };

    this.clearPeople = function(){
      PersonService.clearPeople($scope, controllerScope);
    };
  }])
  .service("PersonService", ["$http", function($http) {

    var refreshCount = 0;
    this.getPeople = function(rootScope, controllerScope){

          var sampleData = [
        {
            "firstName": "Cox",
            "lastName": "Carney",
            "company": "Enormo",
            "employed": refreshCount%2 == 1
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Lorraine",
            "lastName": "Wise",
            "company": "Comveyer",
            "employed": refreshCount%2 == 0
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Nancy",
            "lastName": "Waters",
            "company": "Fuelton",
            "employed": refreshCount%2 == 1
        }
      ];

      $http.post("https://httpbin.org/post", sampleData)
        .success(function(data){
          rootScope.myData = JSON.parse(data.data);
          refreshCount++;
          controllerScope.getPeopleButtonText = "Refresh " + refreshCount;
          controllerScope.errorMessage = "";
        })
        .error(function() {
          controllerScope.errorMessage = "An error has occurred."
        });
    };

    this.clearPeople = function(rootScope, controllerScope) {
      rootScope.myData = [];
      controllerScope.getPeopleButtonText = "Get People";
    }
}]);
```

Is there a better way to structure this code?
Another approach I have read about was to create a ViewService and expose the ViewService into the root scope.

**EDIT Nov 19**
I'm using an Angular Promise to handle the success/error cases of a service call in a controller, rather than inside the service.  This allows me to move view updates into the controller.  Is this the right place to keep the view updates?

```
this.getPeople = function() {
  PersonService.getPeople()
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.myData = JSON.parse(data);
      controllerScope.getPeopleButtonText = "Refresh";
      controllerScope.errorMessage = "";
    }, function(error) {
      controllerScope.errorMessage = "An error has occurred."
    });
};
```

Here's an example plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/tzuSX3aAcUqpH5bM7cIa?p=preview

Comment: Services are generally used for storing and modifying data, or as a container for functions that will be used by many parts of the application. Directives are generally what you use to control the view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use `$rootScope` to store data
2. Use the MVC pattern if you like, so:

One view, has one controller, has as many services as you need.

- Your view shows data which are in the `$scope`
- Your Controller is getting the data from your PersonService
- The PersonService (or just the API service) gets the data from a backend.

Best practices would be like this (**simplyfied**):

**Api.js**

```
angular
    .module( 'api', [])
    .service('Api', Api);

Api.$inject = ['$http'];

function Api($http) {

    var baseUrl = '/api/url/';

    function getPersons() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseUrl + 'YOUR/PERSON/URL'
        });
    }

    return {
       getPersons: getPersons
    }
}
```

**PersonController.js**

```
angular
  .module('personApp')
  .controller('PersonController', PersonController);

PersonController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Api'];

function PersonController($scope, $state, Api) {

  $scope.getPersons = function() {
      Api.getPersons().then(function(response) {
             $scope.persons = response.data;
      }, function(error) {
          // error message
      });
  };
}
```

**Persons.html**

```
<div ng-controller="PersonController">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: persons }" class="grid"></div>
  <button ng-click="getPersons()"></button>
</div>
```

**Summary**

1. Your `view` displays the data which is inside the `$scope`
2. The view has a `controller`, which is there for just getting the data and storing it in the `$scope`, providing the functions for the buttons
3. Your `services` are delivering the data to the controller

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  However, your example doesn't show to deal with the more complex logic from my code, such as displaying a message on a successful HTTP Post call along with updating a ui-grid.  Could you explain more on this?

Comment: Just place a `<span>{{success_message}}</span>` inside the view, and inside the controller, after `$scope.persons`, put a `$scope.success_message = "success message"`; Updating the ui-grid? Just update the scope inside the Controller. Maybe read more about scope and Angular somewhere to understand the basic concepts.